# Angular fire 2 async calls at once but do not process the second callback until the first finishes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, simultaneous

I'm using Angular's $q service to make async requests. I have 2 requests like so (assume I have an angular service named MyService that handles these requests):

```
MyService.Call1().then(function() {
    //do all the first callback's processing here without waiting for call 2
});

MyService.Call2().then(function() {
    //wait for results of first callback before executing this
});
```

I have no guarantee that the second call will finish after the first, but I need the results of call 1 in order to do processing in call 2. I understand that I could chain the promises together, meaning that call 2 waits for call 1 to finish before the request is made, but I want to fire both requests at the same time since I have all the data required to do so. What's the best way to do that?

Edit: I can use the results of the first call immediately. They drive some charts on my page. I don't want the first call to wait on the second call to do its processing. I think that rules out mechanisms like $q.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using `$q.all` would be to use the first promise in the handler for the second. For example

```
var p1 = MyService.Call1().then(function(data) {
    return processedData;
});

MyService.Call2().then(function(call2Data) {
    return p1.then(function(call1Data) {
        // now you have both sets of data
    });
});
```

---

To address some comments, here's how you *could* handle errors / promise rejections without having to wait for both promises to resolve or creating multiple `catch` handlers...

```
var p2 = MyService.Call2().then(function(call2Data) {
    return p1.then(function(call1Data) {
        // now you have both sets of data
    });
});

// use `$q.all` only to handle errors
$q.all([p1, p2]).catch(function(rejection) {
    // handle the error here
});
```

Comment: However, this will get you a *possibly unhandled rejection*  error if `Call1()` rejects before `Call2()` fulfills (and anyway when it rejects). `Promise.all` is there for a reason :-)

Comment: @Bergi no it won't. That's why I have `return p1...` in the `Call2` handler. If `Call1` rejects, then `p1` will be a rejected promise, thus `Call2` will return a rejected promise

Comment: Yes, but it will return a rejected promise only after `Call2()` fulfills, not immediately. Until then, rejections of `Call1()` go unhandled.

Comment: @Bergi you're talking about the end result (the returned promise from Call2). My answer still processes Call1 as soon as it resolves

Comment: Yes, of course I am, because that's where you'd usually handle errors. Obviously, your current code has no error handling whatsoever - but it *would* need 2 error handlers.

Comment: @Bergi no it wouldn't. You'd just add a `catch` to the `Call2` promise. The first rejection will be caught there, much the same was as it would for `$q.all`. See update

Comment: @Bergi I'm happy to keep discussing this but we might need some Plunker examples and a move to the chat system

Comment: No, this would catch rejections from `Call1()` only as soon as `Call2()` is fulfilled (not immediately as if with `all`), or would catch rejections from `Call1()` not at all if `Call2()` is rejected (as opposed to the earlier one for `all`). You can try it out at a plunkr, but trust me :-) Agreed, the differences are subtle.

Comment: @Bergi ah, ok, now I see what you're saying; the main problem being that `Call1` rejections won't be handled if `Call2` rejects, hence requiring two `catch` handlers. I think my update should address this

Answer (score 3):

You can do both calls in parallel with `all`

```
$q.all([MyService.Call1(), MyService.Call2()]).then(function() {
  // ...code dependent on both calls resolving.
});
```

**Edit**:  In response to a comment, there are two things that might interest you.  If you pass an array to `all`, you will find an array of resolutions as the first argument of your function inside of `then`.  If, instead, you pass an object to `all`, you will find an object as your first argument with keys matching the same keys you passed into `all`.

```
$q.all([MyService.Call1(), MyService.Call2()]).then(function(arr) {
  // ...code dependent on the completion of both calls.  The result
  // of Call1 will be in arr[0], and the result of Call2 will be in
  // arr[1]
});
```

...and with objects

```
$q.all({a: MyService.Call1(), b: MyService.Call2()}).then(function(obj) {
  // ...code dependent on the completion of both calls.  The result
  // of Call1 will be in abj.a, and the result of Call2 will be in
  // obj.b
});
```

Comment: Might want to mention the arg passed to the success handler will be an array of `[call1Results, call2Results]`

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear, but I don't want the first call to wait for the second call at all. The first call should be completely independent of everything else. When it finishes, its data is used to render some charts on my page. My understanding of $q.all() is that it waits for all promises to resolve before returning. I updated my question to reflect that.